# Gant chart/ view for C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am looking for free gantt view or gant chart for WPF. I founnd nGantt or WPF Gantt from http://wpfgantt.codeplex.com/. But it does not work. Can any one tell me if exist any other free gantt view or gantt chart. Or can you tell me how to use wpf gantt or ngantt. For me wpf ganntt does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`WPF Gant chart`](http://wpfgantt.codeplex.com/) is the only free and open source control available.

[`nGantt`](https://github.com/danwallentin/nGantt)

There are few other controls which are not free

[`radiantq`](http://radiantq.com/)

[`DlhSoft`](http://dlhsoft.com/DevelopmentComponents.aspx?ViewAll=true&Feature=GanttChartControls)

Comment: can you give me a simple example how to use wpf Gant chart in wpf ?

Comment: @Concarz there is an example provided in the 2nd link

Comment: yes but this is winforms i have a problem how to use wpf gantt in xaml

Comment: @Concarz try this https://github.com/jogibear9988/SlGanttChart

Comment: I was trying this earlier but it does not complile. Do you use anyof this charts ?

Comment: i found Solution with nGantt thanks all for help.