# dynamic gantt chart/view with respective date and time in WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, dynamic, gantt-chart

i'm new to WPF, I'm going to implement Gantt Chart view with respective date and Time
When i tried i can able to plot Gantt-view but not with respective date and Time, can any one help me out from this.

**I want to implement the same with respective of both Time and date dynamically not static.**

Thanks in advance..

Expected Gantt View is
[image]

but current implement as below:
[image]

Below is my WPF code:

```
<Window x:Class="FunctionalFun.UI.ItemsControlExample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:gc="clr-namespace:FunctionalFun.UI"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

    Title="Gantt Example" Height="708" Width="1080">
    <Grid>

        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnHeaderHeight="50" RowHeight="50" ColumnWidth="250" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RenderTransformOrigin="3.25,5.846" Height="526" Width="931" Canvas.Top="70" Canvas.Left="69">

        </DataGrid>
        <Grid Name="firstGrid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Tasks" Type="{x:Type gc:Task}">
                    <gc:Task Name="Task 1" Start="03:45" End="10:10"/>
                </x:Array>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFDEDADA" ShadowDepth="3"/>
            </Grid.Effect>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tasks}" Margin="100,80,0,-100">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <gc:GanttRowPanel MinDate="03:45" MaxDate="23:00"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                    </Style>

                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF007F99" BorderThickness="0.1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF2FD9FD" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCAF6FF" Offset="0.112"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF47D8F7" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Tasks" Type="{x:Type gc:Task}">

                    <gc:Task Name="Task 2" Start="10:10" End="22:00"/>


                </x:Array>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tasks}" Margin="60,120,0,-140">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <gc:GanttRowPanel MinDate="03:45" MaxDate="23:00"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF007F99" BorderThickness="0.1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#d1b57f" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#d1b57f" Offset="0.112"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#d1b57f" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Tasks" Type="{x:Type gc:Task}">

                    <gc:Task Name="Task 3" Start="08:10" End="18:00"/>


                </x:Array>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tasks}" Margin="60,160,0,-180">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <gc:GanttRowPanel MinDate="03:45" MaxDate="23:00"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF007F99" BorderThickness="0.1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#aa4206" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#aa4206" Offset="0.112"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#aa4206" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Tasks" Type="{x:Type gc:Task}">

                    <gc:Task Name="Task 4" Start="03:10" End="11:00"/>

                </x:Array>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tasks}" Margin="60,200,0,-220">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <gc:GanttRowPanel MinDate="03:00" MaxDate="23:00"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF007F99" BorderThickness="0.1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f7dd16" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f7dd16" Offset="0.112"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f7dd16" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Tasks" Type="{x:Type gc:Task}">

                    <gc:Task Name="Task 5" Start="17:10" End="23:00"/>

                </x:Array>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="4"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tasks}" Margin="60,240,0,-260">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <gc:GanttRowPanel MinDate="03:00" MaxDate="23:00"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF007F99" BorderThickness="0.1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#c4ef6e" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#c4ef6e" Offset="0.112"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#c4ef6e" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Tasks" Type="{x:Type gc:Task}">

                    <gc:Task Name="Task 7" Start="07:10" End="17:30"/>

                </x:Array>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="5"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tasks}" Margin="60,280,0,-300">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <gc:GanttRowPanel MinDate="03:00" MaxDate="23:00"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF007F99" BorderThickness="0.1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7bb507" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7bb507" Offset="0.112"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7bb507" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Tasks" Type="{x:Type gc:Task}">

                    <gc:Task Name="Task 6" Start="07:10" End="17:30"/>

                </x:Array>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="7"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tasks}" Margin="60,280,0,-300">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <gc:GanttRowPanel MinDate="03:00" MaxDate="23:00"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                        <Setter Property="gc:GanttRowPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF007F99" BorderThickness="0.1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7bb507" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7bb507" Offset="0.112"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7bb507" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update 1:**

above code is only with respective date, but

I want to implement the same with respective of both Time and date dynamically not static.

Comment: Your question is _too broad_. You're asking us to implement something for you. Instead, be more _specific_, show us where your _isolated_ issue occurs (what _exactly_ doesn't work when you try to implement what you want). Otherwise, this question won't be answered and in worst case will be closed. Also, provide a [mcve] (**minimal** is important) and not the whole code you have.

Comment: Hi, gantt diagrams are quite common, maybe you can spare yourself some time and use an existing implementation. See google or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751866/gant-chart-view-for-c-wpf for example.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using an availabe `Gantt Chart` Control, instead of trying to write your own? For example have a look at that SO Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751866/gant-chart-view-for-c-wpf

Comment: @Stefan - you were a little faster :)

Comment: Actually My question is with respective Time and Date, chart should change RandRandom and Stefan

Comment: dymanoid , I want to implement the same with respective of both Time and date dynamically not static